# I have a shell script which requires a cal command and a text file

Tags: c, linux, shell, text

I am required to write a shell script with the following requirements:

1. Asks for the user's year (for example 2020) of birth,
   using this variable uses the cal command.
2. Saves the output to a file called calendar.txt.
3. Uses the less command on the file to display the
   content of the file to the user.
4. When the less command is exited then use nano on
   this file to change the birthyear at the top from your
   birth year to XXXX.
5. Once you exit nano, use less on the file again and
   display this to the user.

I have been stuck on part 1 and 2 for about a day as this is my first time using C or Linux.

So far I have written this code:

```
#include<stdio.h>                                                               
int main() {                                                                    
int year;                                                                       
                                                                                
printf("Please enter your year of birth");                                      
scanf("%d", &year);                                                             
}
```

But I am unsure of what to do past this. The cal function cannot be called from  within the shell script and when I compile it, it says it doesn't recognise the cal function.

Comment: C is not a shell scripting language. You don’t write shell scripts in C.

Comment: You're supposed to write a _shell script_ , not a _C program_.

Comment: If you are _"required to write a shell script"_ you will fail the course if you hand in a C program.

Comment: *" using this variable uses the cal command"* - It's very unclear what this means

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A C program is not a shell script. C is a compiled language, in opposition to interpreted languages such as shell scripts.

Here is a bash script doing what you want:

```bash
#!/bin/bash

# Before running the program, check if cal is installed
if ! which cal && which nano && which less ; then
    echo "Required programs are not install." >&2
    echo "sudo apt-get install ncal nano less" >&2
    exit 1
fi

# Step 1: Ask the user for their year of birth
read -p "Please enter your year of birth (e.g., 2020): " birth_year

# Step 2: Use the cal command and save the output to calendar.txt
cal $birth_year > calendar.txt

# Step 3: Display the content of the file using the less command
less calendar.txt

# Step 4: Use nano to change the birth year in the file
nano calendar.txt

# Step 5: Display the updated file using the less command
less calendar.txt
```

Save the above code in a file, for example, calendar_script.sh, and make it executable by running the command:

```bash
chmod +x calendar_script.sh
```

To run the script, simply execute it:

```bash
./calendar_script.sh
```

Make sure to have `nano`, `cal` and `less` installed before running the script!

Comment: Cool, free homework writing service! Now I don't have to think for myself :)

Comment: @knittl I think that it's okay if someone doesn't want to do their homework. It's either they are not interested in the field, and will not work in it, or they will be less competent later and will have to work more. In both cases, they have their reasons to ask for help, and we can give them :)

Comment: The question only mentions [tag:shell] so a POSIX compliant shell should be assumed. `read -p` is not defined in POSIX.

Comment: I'm sorry that I'm too stupid to figure out how to use a new programming language in a new Operating System in a couple of days. It's not like I asked my university lecturers to help me with this and they responded with "Find it online." or then tried to find an answer online and still couldn't figure it out.

Comment: Do you think I don't care enough to sink 9k a year into higher education to learn about this? I have no idea how this works. I've been using Python and Java for nearly 5 years at this point and C# for 2.  I don't know how Linux works or C because I haven't had the need to. I asked my question because I want to learn not get out of "doing my homework".

Comment: No worries @Alex, there's no dumb questions, I don't assume anything, that's why I gave an answer to your question :). However StackOverflow community has [mixed feelings about homework questions](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/334822/how-do-i-ask-and-answer-homework-questions))
You can see Shell scripts are the Linux equivalent of CMD on Windows. In your question, you started to ask for a shell script and showed C langage, which is a compile language. There is a fundamental difference between these two languages, and I think that is partially why people didn't take you seriously.